# How to change kapt plugin generate output dir path?

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, kapt

I try to use `kapt` and `vertx-Codegen` to generate my service.But the output path is `/build/generated/source/kapt/main/`. I want `/src/main/generated/`.

Config the `build.gradle.kts`,I find generate `adoc` to `/src/main/generated/`,but other files no change.

[image: my file]

There is `build.gradle.kts`

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
  kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.30"
  kotlin("kapt") version "1.3.30"
  id("io.vertx.vertx-plugin") version "0.8.0"
}
val vertxVersion = "3.8.0"
// ......
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
  kotlinOptions {
    freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
  }
}
dependencies {
  // ....
    implementation("io.vertx:vertx-codegen")
    kapt("io.vertx:vertx-service-proxy:$vertxVersion:processor")
    kapt("io.vertx:vertx-codegen:$vertxVersion:processor")
  // ....
}

kapt{
  arguments {
    arg("codegen.output", project.file("src/main/generated").path)
    arg("kapt.kotlin.generated", project.file("src/main/generated").path)
  }
  javacOptions {
    option("-AoutputDirectory", project.file("src/main/generated").path)
    option("-Acodegen.output", project.file("src/main/generated").path)
  }
}
```

I expect the output path is `/src/main/generated/`, but the actual output path is `/build/generated/source/kapt/main/`. Can you help me...?

Answer (score 0):

**Generating Kotlin sources:**

I managed to solve the problem for generated Kotlin sources by using [javac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) argument:

```
val generatedKotlinSources = project.file("src/main/generated").path
kapt {
    javacOptions {
        option("-Akapt.kotlin.generated=$generatedKotlinSources")
    }
}
```

(Surprisingly `option("-Akapt.kotlin.generated", generatedKotlinSources)` didn't work.)

This solution works with annotation processors using `processingEnv.options["kapt.kotlin.generated"]`, as described on [Annotation Processing with Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html#generating-kotlin-sources) page.

**Generating Java sources:**

However, when generating Java sources, annotation processors use [Filer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Filer.html) initialized with [javac context](https://javadoc.io/static/org.jvnet.sorcerer/sorcerer-javac/0.8/com/sun/tools/javac/util/Context.html). When using Java Annotation Processor, you can override this path by using `-s dir` [javac argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html), but this value is hardcoded in Kapt to `"generated/source/kapt/$sourceSetName"` ([see source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/33a0ec9b4f40f3d6f1f96b2db504ade4c2fafe03/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/internal/kapt/Kapt3KotlinGradleSubplugin.kt#L69)).

**Thus, changing output directory for generated Java doesn't seem possible.**

(And yes, `"generated/source/kaptKotlin/$sourceSetName"` is hardcoded too, but it is used as a default value of `"kapt.kotlin.generated"` option.)